# How can I connect a Snow Leopard computer to a Windows 7 homegroup?

Tags: windows-7, macos, osx-snow-leopard, homegroup

Is there any way to connect to a Windows 7 homegroup from a Mac running Snow Leopard? The computers show up in my Finder on the left side as PCs, but when I try to connect I don't see anything. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The best answer is [this one](https://superuser.com/a/241326) using Finder.

1. In the menu ribbon, click Go, then "Connect to Server" (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>).
2. In the Server Address section enter `smb://Win7Name` (e.g. `smb://homecomputername`)
   or `smb://Win7IPaddress` (e.g. `smb://192.168.1.10`)
3. Enter the username and password for the Windows 7 computer (this works with Windows 8 as well) that you want to connect to

To make it easier, I create a single share in Windows 7 that I want to connect to, then create shortcuts to the folders I want access to in the share. For example:

- SHARE\\

  - MUSIC
  - Photos
  - Movies
  - Documents

That way when I attach to the share, instead of a new drive popping up on the desktop, only one does, with the folders in it.

Of course you have to setup sharing on Windows 7 first (right-click on the folder and choose Sharing from the context menu).

Answer (score 1):

You may not have any services enabled on your Windows computers for the Mac to access (file sharing, VNC, etc).

What are you trying to do other than explore the fact your Mac displays machines in the Network directory?

Answer (score 1):

First of all HomeGroup is not an actual network so your question has noting to do with that just so there is no confusion. (Its a virtual network that is between win7 machines)
Check your network and sharing center that you have your File sharing turned on and the folder that you are tring to share is actually being shared. every new network you connect to windows shuts down this option for security concerns. than you have to check if its a publicly shared folder. if it needs a user name and password just use the ones that you use to login to that win 7 machine. with out further info i dont think i can be more help if i was any at all?

Answer (score 0):

Only Windows 7 OS can access files shared through a HomeGroup. But you can still share files the "old advanced" way, like in Windows Vista. I'm not sure what the steps are though to access Windows file shares from a Mac, but imagine it isn't just hit a button.

Comment: What is the "old advanced" way? I skipped Vista.

Comment: right click, go to properties, sharing tab, and then click advanced sharing.

Answer (score 0):

In Finder;

- Click *Go* from the top menu click *Connect to Server*.
- A window will appear asking for an address.  Usually in windows you'd connect to the PC by typing \computersname. In snow leopard, you type "smb://computersname" or even the other computers IP Address.

You can change your log on details to the username and password of the Windows 7 PC, and your in.

Answer (score -1):

In win XP you can share some folders. Is this removed from win7? Also in winXP you had to create a network or something like that in order to see you PC in the network and make the folder available for accessing.

If you are watching in the finder and you select the win 7 pc. You can "connect as" perhaps you have to logon?